# Alternative to "wide-ranging" adjective for "audience"

Tags: adjectives

What is a good adjective that describes an audience as coming from a wide spectrum of different backgrounds?

Comment: "diverse" audience

Comment: What research have you done youself? What have you found and rejected (and why have you rejected it)? You run the risk of members of the community here repeating your own research.

Comment: Without that information, this is surely [General Reference](http://thesaurus.com/browse/wide-ranging) -- have a look at the *eclectic* tab at that link. ***Eclectic*** is quite a good word, actually.

Comment: **catholic**:  

adj.
1. universal in extent; encompassing all; wide-ranging: (RHK Webster's)

Answer (score 2):

[Heterogenous](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Heterogeneous) can suggest the idea of a very diversified audience:

> composed of parts of different kinds; having widely dissimilar elements or constituents; not homogeneous.